# KeyCloak 7.0.0 throws NullPointerException if select "NO_CACHE" cache policy for User Storage SPI

Tags: java, keycloak

I created an user storage SPI which is to do authentication for users in external database, I can list all users in the "Users" page of KeyCloak and user can log in from keycloak log in page http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/dev/account/. But if I want to get access token from  http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/token, KeyCloak throws exception as below. If I set cache policy as "DEFAULT", KeyCloak works well.

```
09:18:04,972 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-3) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.resolveAttribute(KeycloakModelUtils.java:415)
        at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.UserAttributeMapper.setClaim(UserAttributeMapper.java:101)
        at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper.setClaim(AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper.java:119)
        at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper.transformAccessToken(AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper.java:81)
        at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.TokenManager.transformAccessToken(TokenManager.java:553)
        at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.TokenManager.createClientAccessToken(TokenManager.java:411)
        at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.TokenManager$AccessTokenResponseBuilder.generateAccessToken(TokenManager.java:712)
        at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.resourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant(TokenEndpoint.java:609)
        at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.processGrantRequest(TokenEndpoint.java:190)
```

Comment: I am not able to login if I set NO_CACHE, However, It works if I set as DEFAULT. Any clue what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In you own UserModel implementation, override the method as below to return an empty list if the attribute is not exist.

> @Override
>   public List getAttribute(String name) {
>      final List values = super.getAttribute(name);
>      return Optional.ofNullable(values).orElse(Collections.emptyList());
>   }

Answer (score 0):

I resolved same issue by making my UserModel to extend AbstractUserAdapter so common (and unnecessary for me) methods behaves in standard/non failing way.